# Using photos from network drive with Windows 8 photo app

Tags: network-shares, windows-8, photos

I have photos on my network drive that I want to display (in live tiles preferably in the photo app).

Under `c:\users\paul\pictures` I have made a link to them, using `mklink /d`:

[image]

And this works fine in classic:

[image]

But nothing appears in the photo.app:

[image]

I am guessing that this is an issue with indexing - the photos won't appear until they are indexed, and Windows won't normally index a network drive (unless you make it "available offline, which just copies the files locally) - but this is exactly what the mklink was supposed to work around, and the properties show it is indexable:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: A Photos app team member has [reported this as not present](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/windows-8-photos-app-still-doesnt-support-network/1085f080-03c8-4847-b153-ebcf2a726c4a).

Answer (score 2):

On the Building Windows 8 blog it has been reported that Photos will receive an update for this:

> Photos
>
> - Crop and rotate photos
> - New auto-curated collage slideshows
> - **View photos and videos on network locations in your Pictures Library such as Windows Home Server, network shares, and HomeGroups**
> - Move through photos in your Pictures Library even when you open them from the desktop

— **Source:** [Building Windows 8 - Updating our built-in apps for Windows 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/updating-our-built-in-apps-for-windows-8)

Comment: Cool, so there will be another source we can add in photos app that will include network drives.  I am still curious why the mklink approach doesn't work as a workaround though.

Comment: @Paul: WinRT is a re-implementation, they probably didn't implement symlink support yet.

Comment: This isn't WinRT Tom, it is standard Windows 8.

Comment: Windows 8 uses WinRT for the Metro-style applications, [feel free to read up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) although the first sentence there already suffices: `Windows Runtime, or WinRT, is a cross-platform application architecture on the Windows 8 operating system.` and clarified later: `Applications developed using WinRT for Windows 8 were described by Microsoft as being Metro-style apps`.

Comment: Ooops, my apologies - I thought you meant the RT version.  I am used to the kernel and filesystem mediating access to files, and so dealing with symlinks and such.  I wasn't expecting that the gui runtime would participate.

Comment: So this appears not to have been fixed as of 8/6/13.  This is pathetic!