# How to add network drives to Windows 8's default apps?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using photos from network drive with Windows 8 photo app](https://superuser.com/questions/491388/using-photos-from-network-drive-with-windows-8-photo-app)

I recently bought a Synology DS212j to store all my music, video's and photo's on. 
I mapped all the drives in Explorer and even added links to them in the appropriate Library folders, so far so good.

But when I open the default Windows Music, Video or Photo's app, these folders don't show up in the the library tile. There's also no option to add these folders manually.

So how can I use files stored in network drives in these default apps?

Comment: based on this, it looks like it'll be fixed soon [Using photos from network drive with Windows 8 photo app](http://superuser.com/q/491388)